# Try to connect IP camera but no error found and no stream

Tags: python, opencv

I try to connect live stream of my IP camera with python code but unable to connect. No error and no stream

```
import cv2
import time
import pandas
capture = cv2.VideoCapture('rtsp://192.168.1.13')
a=1
while True:
    a=a+1`enter code here`
    check,frame=capture.read()
    capture = cv2.VideoCapture('rtsp://admin:123456@192.168.1.13')
    print('a')
    print(frame)
    #print('b')
    #print('c')
    cv2.imshow('live',capture)
    print.capture
    print('d')
    cv2.waitKey(1)
print(a)
video.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows
```

Comment: I found that `cv2.VideoCapture` never raise error but it returns information in variable `check` and empty `frame` and this is why you have to check value in variable `check` or `frame` before you try to display frame.

Comment: try with `rtsp://streaming1.osu.edu/media2/ufsap/ufsap.mov` - it is still active stream with short movie.